# bash string manipulation - regex match with delimiter

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a string like this:

```
zone=INTERNET|status=good|routed=special|location=001|resp=user|switch=not set|stack=no|dswres=no|CIDR=10.10.10.0/24|allowDuplicateHost=disable|inheritAllowDuplicateHost=true|pingBeforeAssign=enable|inheritPingBeforeAssign=true|locationInherited=true|gateway=10.10.10.100|inheritDefaultDomains=true|inheritDefaultView=true|inheritDNSRestrictions=true|name=SCB-INET-A
```

The order inside the delimiter `|` can be random - that means the key-value pairs can be randomly ordered in the string.

I want an output string like the following:

```
"INTERNET","10.10.10.0/24","SCB-INET-A"
```

All values in the output are values from the key-value string above

Does anyone know how I can solve this with *awk* or *sed*?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. You've added tags for bash, awk and sed, so I'd expect to see code in all those three as part of your attempt.

Comment: Also use CODE TAGS for your sample(s) Inputs and sample output in your posts.

Comment: Sounds like a homework to me.  Please add what you have tried and what did not work for you.

Comment: So independent from your input, you want to output the values for zone, gateway and name?

Comment: "So independent from your input, you want to output the values for zone, gateway and name?" - exactly

Comment: @EdMorton if you see my messy answer could you please point what's wrong with it or just downvote to give me an idea

Comment: @DmitriChubarov OK, done. See under your answer. I don't feel an urge to downvote it - you gave it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Given your input is a variable var:

```
var="zone=INTERNET|status=good|routed=special|location=001|resp=user|switch=not set|stack=no|dswres=no|CIDR=10.10.10.0/24|allowDuplicateHost=disable|inheritAllowDuplicateHost=true|pingBeforeAssign=enable|inheritPingBeforeAssign=true|locationInherited=true|gateway=10.10.10.100|inheritDefaultDomains=true|inheritDefaultView=true|inheritDNSRestrictions=true|name=SCB-INET-A"

echo "$var" | tr "|" "\n" | sed -n -r "s/(zone|name|gateway)=(.*)/\"\2\"/p" 
"INTERNET"
"10.10.10.100"
"SCB-INET-A"
```

Using another 2 pipes inserts commas and removes line breaks:

```
SOFAR | tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'

"INTERNET","10.10.10.100","SCB-INET-A"
```

Comment: `tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'` can be rewritten as  `paste -sd,`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have name -> value pairs in your input the best approach is to create an array of those mappings (`f[]` below) and then access the values by their names:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="|"; FS="[=\n]"; OFS="," }
{ f[$1] = "\"" $2 "\"" }
END { print f["zone"], f["CIDR"], f["name"] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"INTERNET","10.10.10.0/24","SCB-INET-A"
```

The above will work efficiently (i.e. literally orders of magnitude faster than a shell loop) and portably using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box, unlike all of the other answers so far which all rely on non-POSIX functionality. It does full string matching instead of partial regexp matching, like some of the other answers, so it is extremely robust and will not result in bad output given partial matches. It also will not interpret any input characters (e.g. escape sequences and/or globbing chars), like some of your other answers do, and instead will just robustly reproduce them as-is in the output.

If you need to enhance it to print any extra field values just add them as `, f["<field name>"]` to the print statement and if you need to change the output format or do anything else it's all absolutely trivial too.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
var="zone=INTERNET|status=good|routed=special|location=001|resp=user|switch=not set|stack=no|dswres=no|CIDR=10.10.10.0/24|allowDuplicateHost=disable|inheritAllowDuplicateHost=true|pingBeforeAssign=enable|inheritPingBeforeAssign=true|locationInherited=true|gateway=10.10.10.100|inheritDefaultDomains=true|inheritDefaultView=true|name=SCB-INET-A|inheritDNSRestrictions=true" 

awk -v RS='|' -v ORS=',' -F= '$1~/zone|gateway|name/{print "\"" $2 "\""}' <<<"$var" | sed 's/,$//'
"INTERNET","10.10.10.100","SCB-INET-A"
```

The input record separator `RS` is set to `|`.

The input field separator `FS` is set to `=`.

The output record separator `ORS` is set to `,`.

`$1~/zone|gateway|name/` is filtering the parameter to extract. The `print` statement is added double quote to the parameter value.

The `sed` statement is to remove the annoying last `,` (that the `print` statement is adding).

Answer (score 0):

Not using `sed` or `awk` but the Bash Arrays feature.

```
line="zone=INTERNET|sta=good|CIDR=10.10.10.0/24|a=1 1|...=...|name=SCB-INET-A"

echo "$line" | tr '|' '\n' | {
declare -A vars 
while read -r item ; do 
  if [ -n "$item" ] ; then 
     vars["${item%%=*}"]="${item##*=}"
  fi  
done
echo "\"${vars[zone]}\",\"${vars[CIDR]}\",\"${vars[name]}\"" ; }
```

One advantage of this method is that you always get your fields in order independent of the order of fields in the input line.

Comment: The above will be immensely inefficient compared to, say, an awk solution due to its use of a shell loop (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). It will also interpret escape sequences in the input instead of passing them through as-is, and it will expand globbing chars to match local file names so the output will vary based on the input and the contents of the directory you run it from. The guys who invented shell to manipulate files and processes also invented awk for shell to call to manipulate text so do that.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution using Bash. Not the shortest but I hope it is the best readable and so the best maintainable.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function split_key_val()
#   selects values from a string with key-value pairs
# IN: string_with_key_value_pairs wanted_key_1 [wanted_key_2] ...
# OUT: result
function split_key_val {
  local KEY_VAL_STRING="$1"
  local RESULT
  # read the string with key-value pairs into array
  IFS=\| read -r -a ARRAY <<< "$KEY_VAL_STRING"
  #
  shift
  # while there are wanted-keys ...
  while [[ -n $1 ]]
  do
    WANTED_KEY="$1"
    # Search the array for the wanted-key
    for KEY_VALUE in "${ARRAY[@]}"
    do
      # the key is the part before "="
      KEY=$(echo "$KEY_VALUE" |cut --delimiter="=" --fields=1)
      # the value is the part after "="
      VALUE=$(echo "$KEY_VALUE" |cut --delimiter="=" --fields=2)
      if [[ $KEY == $WANTED_KEY ]]
      then
        # if result is empty; result= found value...
        if [[ -z $RESULT ]]
        then
          # (quote the damned quotes)
          RESULT="\"${VALUE}\""
        else
          # ... else add a comma as a separator
          RESULT="${RESULT},\"${VALUE}\""
        fi
      fi  # key == wanted-key
    done  # searched whole array
    shift # prepare for next wanted-key
  done
  echo "$RESULT"
  return 0
}

STRING="zone=INTERNET|status=good|routed=special|location=001|resp=user|switch=not set|stack=no|dswres=no|CIDR=10.10.10.0/24|allowDuplicateHost=disable|inheritAllowDuplicateHost=true|pingBeforeAssign=enable|inheritPingBeforeAssign=true|locationInherited=true|gateway=10.10.10.100|inheritDefaultDomains=true|inheritDefaultView=true|inheritDNSRestrictions=true|name=SCB-INET-A"

split_key_val "$STRING" zone CIDR name
```

The result is:
    "INTERNET","10.10.10.0/24","SCB-INET-A"

Answer (score 0):

without using more sophisticated text editing tools (as an exercise!)

```
$ tr '|' '\n' <file                          | # make it columnar
  egrep '^(zone|CIDR|name)='                 | # get exact key matches
  cut -d= -f2                                | # get values
  while read line; do echo '"'$line'"'; done | # quote values
  paste -sd,                                   # flatten with comma
```

will give

```
"INTERNET","10.10.10.0/24","SCB-INET-A"
```

you can also replace  `while` statement with `xargs printf '"%s"\n'`